# Are there any recommendations for tools for remote collaboration on Windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, collaboration

The company I work for currently uses "Go To Meeting" to share our desktops but it's quite expensive for what we use it for and we are looking for cheaper (or even free) alternatives.

We have evaluated yuuguu and yugma but they aren't up to scratch. They are both slow and only allow the sharers to share the entire desktop as opposed to individual applications.

The functionality we need is to specify which application is shared and also to give the viewers permission to control the mouse and keyboard. Everything else would be an added bonus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. None of the options provided were what we were looking for. We are going to try Microsoft SharedView, seems to have the functionality we require:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=95AF94BA-755E-4039-9038-63005EE9D33A&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

I use [CrossLoop](http://www.crossloop.com) and it works well, it is free!

Answer (score 0):

I use [LogmeIn](http://logmein.com/) and [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/vpn.asp), for remote desktop and VPN solutions. They have free and paid plans.

Answer (score 0):

[[image] Remobo](https://download.cnet.com/Remobo/3000-7240_4-10778933.html) works quite well too

> All network traffic in Remobo are end-to-end encrypted with 256-bit AES algorithm, and only the chart participants have the keys to decrypt the message. Plus, Remobo's file transfer is fast & safe, because all computers in a Remobo User's Instant Private Network (IPN) have direct network connections to each other; messages are relayed via Servers from Remobo.com only if direct connection cannot be established.
>
> It NOT require any configuration on any of your existing networking devices, and you do not need to add any new hardware devices into your network to run Remobo

Comment: My broken image repairer found this post; not sure if the tool is still useful or not.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you. I think for the purpose of this 12+ years old answer, it will be useful enough.