# Monitoring Eclipse Window Acceptance

Tags: eclipse, evaluation

I know that the Eclipse Foundation has a program within Eclipse (I guess it is a plugin) that can monitor the user behaviour. E.g. What window was used how many times.

I forgot the name of that program. Is it possible to use the plugin in a company to monitor how the programmers use Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **[Eclipse Usage Data Collector](https://www.eclipse.org/epp/usagedata/)** (UDC), with its [user guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20200918205201/https://www.eclipse.org/org/usagedata/userguide.php)

> At present, the UDC does not expose any official APIs, though there are several under consideration

So, I am not sure you could reuse it *directly* for internal use. They have a [mailing list](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/epp-dev/2021/Mar/index.html), though, were you could get a confirmation about that kind of project.

You could may be try and change the "upload address" (if you can setup a compatible server):

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org/org/usagedata/images/UploadingPrefs.png))</sub>

The data captures are [visible here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926094207/http://www.eclipse.org/org/usagedata/results.php).

Comment: @Glorfindel as always (for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/205848/6309), thank you so much for your work on restoring broken pictures. This is very much appreciated.